# Xj3D file size limit to display

Tags: java, netbeans, x3d

I'm making an Xj3D java class that displays `X3D` files. I have some `X3D` files that are small in size, around 1 or 2KB that get displayed in the java class, but when I swap them out with the files that I want to display that are much bigger, which range from 525KB to 20,459KB in size, they don't get displayed, I've tried to convert them by using `X3D-Edit` to `X3DV` files but they don't get converted properly and they get emptied and have nothing in. I have `X3D-Edit` installed and working with Netbeans and the version I've got is Netbeans 8.1 and the version of `X3D-Edit` is `X3D-Edit 3.3`

My question is, is there a file size limit that works for `Xj3D` to work? Or do I need to configure `X3D-Edit` to work or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Actually 20 MB is not really big. Did you check your java memory heap size?

Comment: @Endery I'm unsure how I'd check that. I'll have a look into it and see if it helps